# Rename MongoDB Child Collection Property

Tags: mongodb, rename

I have a Tenant collection, and each Tenant entity has a TenantLeases child list. A TenantLease entity has a MonthlyRent property, which I'm trying to rename to Rent. Here is what I tried:

```
db.Tenant.update( { "TenantLeases.MonthlyRent": { $exists:true } }, { $rename: { "TenantLeases.MonthlyRent": "TenantLeases.Rent" } }, false, true);
```

**$rename source field invalid**

```
db.Tenant.update( { "TenantLeases.$.MonthlyRent": { $exists:true } }, { $rename: { "TenantLeases.$.MonthlyRent": "TenantLeases.$.Rent" } }, false, true);
```

**$rename source may not be dynamic array**

Clearly $rename isn't going to work, so now I'm trying to iterate through and rename the TenantLeases, however I'm not sure how to update a specific array item:

```
db.Tenant.find().forEach(function(tenant) {
   if(tenant.TenantLeases) {
      for(var k=0;k<tenant.TenantLeases.length;k++) {
         db.Tenant.update( { "TenantLeases." + k + ".MonthlyRent": { $exists:true } }, { $rename: { "TenantLeases." + k + ".MonthlyRent": "TenantLeases." + k + ".Rent" } }, false, false);//gives syntax error
      }
   }
});
```